# Backend and Frontend framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, signalr, frontend, backend

My internship mentor asked me to build a customized MVP framework in .net, for asp.net that contains ready to use responsive component, is it correcte to think that way, I mean mixing backend with front end in the same library? I thought about integrating signalR so I can build  generic 'live' user controls, but after a couple of tutorials I came out to the conclusion that I am wasting my time. Am I right?

Comment: Don't use SignalR just for the hell of it, unless you run into some specific requirement where it's appropriate.

Comment: the guy didn't give me any requirement except for the MVP pattern,tracking users' activities, excel and pdf conversion utilities, and responsivity layer, MVP is already done,Pdf and excel are very easy, the reponsivity is my only problem and even him doesn't  know what he wants

Comment: What are you understanding by "responsive"?

Comment: when asked him the same question he told me to look at Ext Js

Comment: Well I don't know what he means by it, so I don't want to mislead you, but in the context of web UI design it has a specific meaning: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design